# proving $n$-ary associativity/commutivity of multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

EDIT: I tried to do the induction myself... looks pretty solid to me, what do you guys think?

**Basis:** $a\cdot b\cdot c$
Show all possible cases for 3 terms (using commutivity and associativity) and that order of multiplication doesnt matter.

**Induction:**

Assume true for k: $(a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...\cdot a_{k})$

This $=>$ that it is also true for any $x<k$ as well... because we can just replace numbers we're not interested in being multiplied by 1's.

Now we have: $(a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...\cdot a_{k})\cdot a_{k+1}$

Since its true for k... we can list all possible combinations of those operations. Then for each of those possible operations we multiply each of them by $a_{k+1}$ and list them. (Now we have covered every order possibility with $a_{k+1}$ as the end term.) Then using associativity and commutivity we do this step of moving the k+1 term one over to the left:

$(a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...\cdot a_{k})\cdot a_{k+1}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-1})\cdot a_{k})\cdot a_{k+1}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-1})\cdot (a_{k}\cdot a_{k+1})$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-1})\cdot (a_{k+1}\cdot a_{k})$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-1})\cdot a_{k+1})\cdot a_{k}$

Now with the $a_{k+1}$ term being part of the 1st k terms being multiplied (for which we know that the order of multiplication doesnt matter) we once again list all the possible orders of multiplication. Now we have listed every possibility with $a_{k+1}$ as the second last term.

Then once again we move the [$a_{k+1}$ term] one position to the left again (with associativity and commutivity). ie:

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-2}\cdot a_{k-1})\cdot a_{k+1})\cdot a_{k}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-2})\cdot a_{k-1})\cdot a_{k+1})\cdot a_{k}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-2})\cdot (a_{k-1}\cdot a_{k+1})\cdot a_{k}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-2})\cdot (a_{k+1}\cdot a_{k-1})\cdot a_{k}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-2})\cdot a_{k+1})\cdot a_{k-1})\cdot a_{k}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-2}\cdot a_{k+1})\cdot a_{k-1})\cdot a_{k}$ =

$((a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot ...a_{k-2}\cdot a_{k+1})\cdot (a_{k-1}\cdot a_{k})$

Now we list all possible orders left of and including the k+1 term and then for each of the resulting possibilities we multiply them with all possible orders of the terms to the right hand side of the k+1 term. We can do this each time because each of the terms are <=k.

Then we keep repeating this process until k+1 is the very first term and we have all possible orders of multiplication. Therefore k=>k+1 and we have shown the induction step.

---

Could someone please point me to a proof by induction that for any number of operands the order of multiplication is not important...e.g.:
$$abcdefgh=gbadchef$$
(I don't think this can be done with just associativity because the way "$gb$" are bracketed in the 2nd expression is impossible to bracket in the 1st expression). But Id like a generalized $n$-ary proof for any multiplication operation not just the example above. I've seen this done for associativity but never for commutativity AND associativity.

Comment: First show the result about associativity, so that you don't need to worry about parantheses. Then the inductive proof about commutativity is straightforward.

Comment: (NB. I'm _not_ a "$bad\, chef$" :).)

Comment: Im not asking anyone to type it up, just if someone could point me to a web link/textbook that has this.. I cant find it anywhere..

Comment: @tom Hungerford's Algebra has a proof of this. You can find it as Theorem 1.6 and Corollary 1.7 of Chapter 1. You will also need the recursion theorem from the introduction.